# Dynamically populate dropdown from database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I am looking to do this :

I have two field 
1. Date - using jquery datepicker 
2. DropDown - Populated with student id

So , when i select a date say 03/09/2012 i should get all student id present on that day (say 15 of them) , then when i change the date to 04/09/2012 i should get id of only student that are present on that day ( say 29 of them)

I have done is , i have made ajax call to query the database like :

```
$('#date_selected').blur(function(){
$.ajax({
//query database and get the array of student id present on that date
//but from jquery how do i know populate my dropdown ?
//i would probably get the results json encoded
});
});
```

No issues about getting the data, i just want to know how to populate the dropdown using the array(json) that i have

Comment: there are a lot of tutorials and answers about this please search the net before asking answer here by the way look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11305905/populate-dropdown-from-database-in-codeigniter

Comment: @raheeshan : He is asking for ajax call where he gets the json string only. he doesn't want whole html in ajax request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this inside your ajax success function:

```
data = $.parseJSON(data);

var select_fields = data.selectf;

var select_id = "/*ID OF SELECT FIELD*/";

$('#'+select_id+' option').remove();

for(var x  in select_fields){
    $('#'+select_id).append($('<option value="'+select_fields[x]['value']+'">'+select_fields[x]['name']+'</option>'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use datepicker `onselect` method

```
 $('#date_selected').datepicker({
    onSelect:function (selectedDate) {
       //make your jquery ajax post here
    }
   });
```

Comment: he want how to append data not event